# Task management program in Python

Tags: python

I made a simple program in Python

- stores tasks in the file
- allows the user to manage them.

I'm interested if my implementation is efficient and could I do something better. I'm not sure whether loading all data from file to memory and again saving it in the file is a good way to implement list saving tasks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os


CHOICE_LIST_TASKS = 1
CHOICE_ADD_TASK = 2
CHOICE_REMOVE_TASK = 3
CHOICE_QUIT = 4


def read_int(prompt='> ', errmsg='Invalid number!'):
    num = None
    while num is None:
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)
    return num


def display_menu():
    print('What do you want to do?')
    print('[1] List all tasks')
    print('[2] Add a new task')
    print('[3] Delete task')
    print('[4] Quit')


choice = None
file = None
if not os.path.exists('tasks'):
    file = open('tasks', 'w+')
else:
    file = open('tasks', 'r+')
tasks = []

for line in file.readlines():
    tasks.append(line.strip())

while choice != CHOICE_QUIT:
    display_menu()
    choice = read_int()
    if choice == CHOICE_LIST_TASKS:
        if len(tasks) == 0:
            print('Task list is empty!')
        else:
            print('Tasks:')
            for x in tasks:
                print(x)
    elif choice == CHOICE_ADD_TASK:
        desc = input('Which task do you want to do? ')
        index = tasks.append(desc)
        print('Successfully added a new task!')
    elif choice == CHOICE_REMOVE_TASK:
        if len(tasks) == 0:
            print('Task list is empty!')
        else:
            for x in tasks:
                print(tasks.index(x), x)
            index = read_int('Which task do you want to delete? ')
            try:
                tasks.pop(index)
                print('Successfully deleted task!')
            except IndexError:
                print('Please enter proper task number')
    elif choice == CHOICE_QUIT:
        print('Good bye!')
    else:
        print('Invalid choice!')

file = open('tasks', 'w+')
for x in tasks:
    file.write(x + '\n')
```

Comment: you started off strong with functions, and then its all one big blob of code segment?

Comment: consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the very top.

```py
CHOICE_LIST_TASKS = 1
CHOICE_ADD_TASK = 2
CHOICE_REMOVE_TASK = 3
CHOICE_QUIT = 4
```

It's clear to me that you want to create variables and assign them certain integers so you don't have to use magic numbers anywhere, kudos to you for this. There is a much better way to implement this idea in python

## Enumerations : `Enum`

**[Enumerations in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)**

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names 
> (members) bound to unique, constant values

### creating an `Enum`

```py
class Choices(Enum):
    list_task = 1
    add_task = 2 
    remove_task = 3
    quit = 4
```

This already looks much clearer than random global variables. You can also [iterate through the enumeration and display its values with names](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/data-structures-and-algorithms/python-data-structure-exercise-2.php) .

```py
print(Choices.add_task.name)
```

> add_task

```py
print(Choices.add_task.value)
```

> 1

## Use more functions

```py
file = None
if not os.path.exists('tasks'):
    file = open('tasks', 'w+')
else:
    file = open('tasks', 'r+')
tasks = []

for line in file.readlines():
    tasks.append(line.strip())
```

Why can't we move this into a function called `read_task_file()`?
This way it is extremely clear to me, you, you after a year reading old projects, and anybody else who will ever read this code that those few lines of code **will read the task file**. Without that, one must read the code thoroughly and understand its purpose.

```py
def read_task_file():
    file = None
    if not os.path.exists('tasks'):
        file = open('tasks', 'w+')
    else:
        file = open('tasks', 'r+')
    tasks = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        tasks.append(line.strip())
    return tasks
```

now getting the tasks is

```py
tasks = read_task_file()
```

This exact same applies to the next set of code, which will let the user enter their choice so we can perform it.

Factoring out the part where we read a choice from the user and perform  into a function would look like

```py
def read_task_choice():
    display_menu()
    choice = read_int()
    if choice not in Choices._value2member_map_:
        print("Invalid input! Please enter a correct choice\n")
        read_task_choice()
```

Note: `Choices._value2member_map_` will be all the values in an enumeration.

This already looks much cleaner! We eliminate the need of having it in a loop where it will check all the cases, the function only returns `choice` when there is a valid input.

As I said, factor out the work into functions and all them when required. I have done the same for the 4 main jobs ( the 4 choices ).

---

### List tasks

```py
def list_tasks(tasks):
    if len(tasks) == 0:
        print("Task list is empty!")
        return None


    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        print(f"{i} {tasks[i]}")
```

### Add new task

```py
def add_new_task(tasks):
    return input("What task would you like to finish ?: ")
    tasks.append(task)
```

### Remove task

```py
def remove_task(tasks):
    if len(tasks) == 0:
        print("Task list is already empty!")
        return None

    list_tasks(tasks)
    task = int(input(("Which task would you like to remove: ?")))

    if task < 0 or task >= len(tasks):
        print("Invalid input! Please select an appropriate task")
        remove_task(tasks)
    tasks.pop(task)
```

And finally

### Update task file

```py
def update_task_file(tasks):
    file = open('tasks', 'w+')
    for x in tasks:
        file.write(x + '\n')
```

What is the point of having millions of functions when I can put everything like I have already done?
Now when you have to play the game

```py
tasks = read_task_file()

while True:
    choice = read_task_choice()
    if choice == Choices.list_task.value:
        list_tasks(tasks)

    elif choice == Choices.add_task.value:
        add_new_task(tasks)
        

    elif choice == Choices.remove_task.value:
        remove_task(tasks)

    else:
        break

    update_task_file(tasks)
```

This is the main advantage of having strongly typed functions.

## Clearing the screen and waiting for input

Due to the absence of Graphics, we can see that after a few choices the terminal looks a little strange[image: terminal]

We can improve this by simply clearing the screen after each choice, and then wait for the user to press a key

### Clearing the terminal

There are a few ways. A popular way is to use `os.system("cls")` if you're on windows, but calling this is quite expensive and also makes your program more platform dependant.

You can do

```py
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

And this will also work.

### Waiting for input

Adding this line `input("Press any key to continue...")` will wait for the user's response before displaying all the choices again, making the experience better.

### Final

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from enum import Enum

class Choices(Enum):
    list_task = 1
    add_task = 2
    remove_task = 3
    quit = 4

def read_int(prompt='> ', errmsg='Invalid number!'):
    num = None
    while num is None:
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)
    return num

def display_menu():
    print('What do you want to do?')
    print('[1] List all tasks')
    print('[2] Add a new task')
    print('[3] Delete task')
    print('[4] Quit')

def read_task_file():
    file = None
    if not os.path.exists('tasks'):
        file = open('tasks', 'w+')
    else:
        file = open('tasks', 'r+')
    tasks = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        tasks.append(line.strip())
    return tasks

def update_task_file(tasks):
    file = open('tasks', 'w+')
    for x in tasks:
        file.write(x + '\n')

def read_task_choice():
    display_menu()
    choice = read_int()
    if choice not in Choices._value2member_map_:
        print("Invalid input! Please enter a correct choice\n")
        read_task_choice()
    return choice

def add_new_task(tasks):
    task = input("What task would you like to do: ")
    tasks.append(task)

def list_tasks(tasks):
    if len(tasks) == 0:
        print("Task list is empty!")
        return None


    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        print(f"{i} {tasks[i]}")

def remove_task(tasks):
    if len(tasks) == 0:
        print("Task list is already empty!")
        return None

    list_tasks(tasks)
    task = int(input(("Which task would you like to remove: ?")))

    if task < 0 or task >= len(tasks):
        print("Invalid input! Please select an appropriate task")
        remove_task(tasks)
    tasks.pop(task)

def clear_screen():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")

def pause():
    input("Press any key to continue...")

tasks = read_task_file()

while True:
    clear_screen()
    choice = read_task_choice()
    if choice == Choices.list_task.value:
        list_tasks(tasks)

    elif choice == Choices.add_task.value:
        add_new_task(tasks)


    elif choice == Choices.remove_task.value:
        remove_task(tasks)

    else:
        break

    update_task_file(tasks)
    pause()
```