# Python history quiz program

Tags: python, quiz

This program allows users to manage questions and quiz users from years of historical events. I'm looking for suggestions on how can I better organize my code, maybe apply OOP for functions and avoid using global variable `data_filename`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from enum import Enum
import os
import pickle
import random


data_filename = 'program.obj'


def read_int(prompt='> ', errmsg='Invalid number!'):
    number = None
    while number is None:
        try:
            number = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)
    return number


def display_menu():
    print('What do you want to do?')
    print('[1] List all historical events')
    print('[2] Add event')
    print('[3] Remove event')
    print('[4] Quiz')
    print('[5] Statistics')
    print('[6] Clear statistics') # TODO: move to options submenu
    print('[7] Exit')


def clear_screen():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")


def pause():
    input('Press any key to continue...')


def yes_or_no(prompt='Proceed? [y|n]\n> ', errmsg='Valid answers are y and n.'):
    answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    while answer != 'y' and answer != 'n':
        print(errmsg)
        answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    return answer


def read_data_file():
    file = open(data_filename, 'a+b')
    file.seek(0)
    data = {'events': [], 'statistics': {'total_successes': 0, 'total_failures': 0}}
    if os.path.getsize(data_filename) > 0:
        data = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    return data


def list_events(data):
    events = data['events']
    if len(events) == 0:
        print('Event list is empty!')
    else:
        print('Historical events:')
        for event in events:
            print(event)


def add_event(data):
    events = data['events']
    year = read_int(prompt='Enter year: ')
    description = input('Enter description: ')
    events.append({'year': year, 'description': description})
    print('Successfully added a new historical event!')


def remove_event(data):
    events = data['events']
    if len(events) == 0:
        print('Event list is empty!')
    else:
        for event in events:
            print(events.index(event), event)
        index = read_int('Which event do you want to delete? ')
        try:
            events.pop(index)
            print('Successfully deleted event!')
        except IndexError:
            print('Number out of range!')


def quiz(data):
    events = data['events']
    stats = data['statistics']
    if len(events) == 0:
        print('Event list is empty!')
    else:
        num = read_int(prompt='How many questions should I ask? ')
        if 0 < num <= len(events):
            for event in random.sample(events, num):
                print(event['description'])
                year = read_int('In which year was following event occurred? ')
                if year == event['year']:
                    stats['total_successes'] += 1
                    print('Good answer!')
                else:
                    stats['total_failures'] += 1
                    print('Bad answer!')
        elif num < 0:
            print('Number of questions can\'t be negative!')
        else:
            print('Too much questions!')


def display_stats(data):
    stats = data['statistics']
    tries = stats['total_successes'] + stats['total_failures']
    if tries == 0:
        total_successes = 0
        total_failures = 0
    else:
        total_successes = stats['total_successes']/tries * 100
        total_failures = stats['total_failures']/tries * 100
    print('Statistics')
    print('Total: {0:10.2f}% successes, {1:10.2f}% failures'.format(total_successes, total_failures))


def clear_stats(data):
    answer = yes_or_no('Are you sure you want to clear statistics? [y|n]\n> ')
    if answer == 'y':
        data['statistics'] = {'total_successes': 0, 'total_failures': 0}
        print('Successfully cleared statistics!')
    else:
        print('Statistics left unchanged.')


# TODO: settings submenu
# def settings(data):
#     print('-' * 10)
#     print('Program settings')
#     print('-' * 10)
#     print('[1] Clear statistics')
#     print('[2] Back')
#     user_choice = read_int()
#     while user_choice != 2:
#         if user_choice == 1:
#             clear_stats(data)


def update_data_file(data):
    file = open(data_filename, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, file)
    file.close()


class Choices(Enum):
    list_events = 1
    add_event = 2
    remove_event = 3
    quiz = 4
    statistics = 5
    clear_stats = 6
    exit = 7


program_data = read_data_file()
choice = None
while choice != Choices.exit.value:
    clear_screen()
    display_menu()
    choice = read_int()
    if choice == Choices.list_events.value:
        list_events(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.add_event.value:
        add_event(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.remove_event.value:
        remove_event(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.quiz.value:
        quiz(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.statistics.value:
        display_stats(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.clear_stats.value:
        clear_stats(program_data)
    elif choice == Choices.exit.value:
        print('Good bye!')
    else:
        print('Invalid choice!')
    update_data_file(program_data)
    pause()
```

Comment: awesome, i'd say the code is much more readable than [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250339/task-management-program-in-python)

Comment: As always with python, I suggest to apply black : https://pypi.org/project/black/

Comment: Use a "with" context handler for opening / closing files

Answer (score 2):

### Constants

`data_filename` should be capitalized, since it's a global constant.

### Early-return

There's no need to use `number` as the condition on your `while`; instead:

```
number = None
while number is None:
    try:
        number = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print(errmsg)
return number
```

can be

```
while True:
    try:
        return int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print(errmsg)
```

### Menu management

`display_menu` could use a sequence of tuples, better yet a sequence of named tuples or `@dataclass`es, each having a title string attribute and a callable attribute. Then your `display_menu` could be

```
print('What do you want to do?')
print('\n'.join(f'[{i}] {item.title}' for i, item in enumerate(menu, 1)))
```

I see that you also have a `Choices` enum. That's not bad, and you could potentially use both an enum and the suggestion above, so long as you have a dictionary of enum-choices-to-function-references.

### Membership tests

```
answer != 'y' and answer != 'n'
```

can be

```
answer not in {'y', 'n'}
```

### Loop structure

Avoid having to call `input` twice; this:

```
answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
while answer != 'y' and answer != 'n':
    print(errmsg)
    answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
return answer
```

can be

```
while True:
    answer = input(prompt).strip().lower()
    if answer in {'y', 'n'}:
        return answer
    print(errmsg)
```

### File operations

```
file = open(data_filename, 'a+b')
file.seek(0)
```

has a few issues:

- Newly-opened file handles do not need an initial seek-to-beginning; that's redundant if you open in read-binary mode
- You should be using `with` and avoiding an explicit `close()`
- You should only bother to initialize your default `data` when needed
- You want to check whether the file exists, not its size

So:

```
if os.path.exists(data_filename):
    with open(data_filename, 'rb') as file:
        return pickle.load(file)
return {'events': [], 'statistics': {'total_successes': 0, 'total_failures': 0}}
```

### Redundant predicates

```
if 0 < num <= len(events):
    ...
elif num < 0:
    print('Number of questions can\'t be negative!')
else:
    print('Too much questions!')
```

needs to be re-thought. First, `too much questions` should be `too many questions`. Also, what if the user enters 0? Surely that's not "too many questions", but that's what will be printed. Suggested:

```
if num < 1:
    print('Not enough questions.')
elif num > len(events):
    print('Too many questions.')
else:
    ...
```

### Stronger-typed, stronger-structured data

```
stats['total_successes'] + stats['total_failures']
```

is an example of what I've seen called "data pasta". Dictionaries are being abused, here, when something like a `@dataclass` containing type hints is more appropriate.

### String interpolation

```
'Total: {0:10.2f}% successes, {1:10.2f}% failures'.format(total_successes, total_failures)
```

is more easily expressed as

```
(
    f'Total: {total_successes:10.2f}% successes, '
    f'{total_failures:10.2f}% failures'
)
```

The line split is optional but better for legibility.

### String escapes

```
'Number of questions can\'t be negative!'
```

is more easily written as

```
"Number of questions can't be negative!"
```

Comment: I have an issue with your answer. If a file exists, without `file.seek(0)` I'm getting `EOFError: Ran out of input`. Otherwise, this program instead of creating a file and returning empty settings object throws exception `FileNotFoundError`. Code: https://dpaste.com/7ULK8KJYD

Comment: That's deeply strange. Is it a normal file, or a FIFO (etc)?

Comment: This is a normal file. Maybe I'll send the complete project code?

Comment: Oh, I see what's happening. You open in append mode, but then seek? Why?

Comment: You should just be opening in read-binary mode.

Comment: I open in the append mode because I want the file to be created before reading. I have an another issue if file doesn't exist function `os.path.getsize(DATA_FILENAME)` throws an exception `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: I mean, yes? What else would you expect? If a file doesn't exist, what do you think its size should be?

Comment: Problem solved. Changed if statement condition to `os.path.exists(DATA_FILENAME) and os.path.getsize(DATA_FILENAME) > 0`.